# Is it possible to export a div having an id with all its contents using R & Shiny as done for example in javascript with JsPdf?

Tags: r, shiny, jspdf, shinyapps, shinyjs

I know the question is a bit silly but hey it's worth it. Usually, when exporting files with datatables in R and Shiny it's quite easy but today I would like to be able to export all the content of a div which contains for example paragraphs, html tables and etc... without however losing the CSS, is it possible to do this with R and Shiny?

```
library(shiny)

#UI
ui = fluidPage(
  downloadButton("download", "Print as pdf"),
  fluidRow(
    box(width = 12,id="PS1AGLOBAL",dataTableOutput("table_pse1aglobal"),title="",
      collapsible = T,
       fluidRow(
        column(10, #wellPanel(p("Column width 8"))),
        column(2,tags$p(style="position: relative; top: -15px;", "PSE 1A global"))),
        fluidRow(
                  column(8, tags$p(style="text-decoration: underline; text-transform: capitalize; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 2px;", "DECLARATION")
         ),
     column(4)
    ),
    fluidRow(
      uiOutput("generated_declaration")
    ),
 )

 #SERVER

 server <- function(input, output, session) {
  downloadHandler(
  filename = function () {
    #i don't know
  }
)
   }
   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I don't know if I have posed my problem correctly, but I just want to export the content of the div with the id "table_pse1aglobal" in a pdf file when a button is clicked. I am open to any suggestions thank you.

Comment: @ismirsehregal thanks to you, I didn't notice it when I was posting, so it overwhelmed me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [capture](https://github.com/dreamRs/capture) package.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(capture) # remotes::install_github("dreamRs/capture")

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  capture::capture_pdf(
    selector = "#PS1AGLOBAL",
    filename = "box.pdf",
    icon("camera"), 
    "Take PDF screenshot."
  ),
  fluidRow(
    box(
      width = 12,
      id = "PS1AGLOBAL",
      h1("HELLO"),
      title = "TITLE",
      collapsible = TRUE,
      fluidRow(
        column(
          10,
          column(
            2,
            tags$p(style = "position: relative; top: -15px;", "PSE 1A global")
          )
        ),
        fluidRow(
          column(
            8,
            tags$p(
              style = "text-decoration: underline; text-transform: capitalize; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 2px;",
              "DECLARATION"
            )
          ),
          column(4)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# SERVER

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This package is not on CRAN. Maybe **shinyscreenshot** can achieve the same result, and this package is on CRAN.

---

## EDIT

Looks like that does not work well with the `box`, so put it inside a `div`:

```r
  fluidRow(
    div(
      id = "PS1AGLOBAL",
      box(
        width = 12,
        h1("HELLO"),
        title = "TITLE",
        collapsible = TRUE,
        fluidRow(
          column(
            10,
            column(
              2,
              tags$p(style = "position: relative; top: -15px;", "PSE 1A global")
            )
          ),
          fluidRow(
            column(
              8,
              tags$p(
                style = "text-decoration: underline; text-transform: capitalize; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: 2px;",
                "DECLARATION"
              )
            ),
            column(4)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I replaced the box with the div as requested but, when I click on the button to capture, nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm I had some problems too but it finally worked. Maybe **capture** does not like `box`.

Comment: Can you tell me how you did in the end? because so far at home it does not work! did you change anything in the code yet?

Comment: I changed nothing. Looks like it randomly works.

Comment: Hi @Laurent, I come back to you today to say thank you because, I have just solved my problem. Your solution actually works. After much research, an idea came to my mind to inspect the console to see what could be blocking since at the code level, there was no error and therefore, I realized that it was a cross-origin issue (CORS) that was caused by the R window so I just opened in a browser and everything worked fine. I tried with the screenshot and capture libraries and both work perfectly
Thank you very much, I'll mark it as solved.